# Jquery/javascript creating object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

So, I want to create an object (semi-automatically) using Jquery.

Instead of posting all of my code here, I'll give an example of what I want to do:

```
var myobject = {
   'name1': {
     'coord1':true,
     'coord2':false,
     'coord3':false,
   },
   'name2': {
     'coord4':true,
    'coord5':false,
    'coord6':false,
  }
}
```

1) I first want to check if 'nameX' is already in my object, if so, continue to step 2, if not, I want to add the name, and coordX with value true or false.

2) If 'nameX' is in the array, I want to check i 'coordX' is in the array. If so, I need to check if the corresponding value (true or false) is the same, and if not, replace it. If 'CoordX' is not in the object, I want to add it with the corresponding value.

For example:

```
var mynewname = 'name3';
var mynewcoord = 'coord5';
var mynewvalue = 'true';
var mynewname2 = 'name1';
var mynewcoord2 = 'coord4';
var mynewvalue = 'false';
```

When checking these values with the object this should give:

```
var myobject = {
  'name1': {'
    coord1':true,
    'coord2':false,
    'coord3':false,
    'coord4':false
  },
  'name2': {
    'coord4':true,
    'coord5':false,
    'coord6':false
  },
  'name3':{
    'coord5':true
  }
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you

Comment: 1. This has nothing to do with jQuery. 2. You have no arrays there, they're *objects*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find out if an object contains a property with a given name, you have a couple of choices.

You can use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) with a string property name:

```
if ("nameX" in myobject) {
    // The object referenced by `myobject` (or its prototype)
    // has its own property called "nameX"
}
else {
    // It doesn't
}
```

`in` will check the object and its prototype. That probably doesn't matter for the simple objects you're using.

Or you can use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), which only checks the object and not its prototype:

```
if (myobject.hasOwnProperty("nameX")) {
    // The object referenced by `myobject` has its own property called "nameX"
}
else {
    // It doesn't
}
```

So for instance, if you want to see if `name1` is in `myobject` and, if not, add `name1` referencing a blank object, you'd do this:

```
if (!("name1" in myobject)) {
    myobject.name1 = {}; // No, add it and give it a blank object as its value
}
```

And similarly for the `coordX` properties of the objects you're referencing from `myobject.nameX`.

Comment: So say I want to check for a certain coordX within a certain name, could I just use if ("coordX" in myobject.name)) {} ?

Comment: @user3117628: Assuming `name` is a property of `myobject` and it refers to an object, yes. So for instance, `"coord2" in myobject.name1` is `true` if the object referenced by `myobject.name1` has a property called `coord2`.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept your answer in 4 minutes :)